# How to find if a value is in an array in Visual C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, visual-studio, search

If I have an array of ints, and I want to quickly check if a certain int value is in that array, is there a method to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the array is sorted, then this is quickest:

```
Array.BinarySearch(myArray, value) >= 0;
```

If the array is searched a lot and rarely modified, then you may find it worthwhile to sort the array after modification (using `Array.Sort`) and use the above. Otherwise, use the option you prefer:

```
Array.IndexOf(myArray, value) >= 0; //.Net 1

Array.Exists(array, delegate(int x) { return x == value; }); //.Net 2

myArray.Contains(value); //.Net 3
```

`IndexOf` has the best performance for unsorted arrays. The second option uses a predicate delegate, and the third requires the creation of an enumerator object.

Comment: This new Contains method is not well publicized.

Answer (score 4):

Use for example this, if you want to check if your array contains the int 0:

```
if (your_int_array.Contains(0))
{
    //Code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Enumerable.Contains() Method is your friend in .NET-Framework 3.5...

Comment: Providing you are using .NET 3.5

Answer (score 2):

[Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) if you're using C# 3.0 or later.

e.g.

```
var contained = myArray.Contains(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat.aspx) method:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
bool isArrayContains17 = Array.IndexOf(array, 17) > -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = new []  { 1, 2};
if myArray.Contains(1)
{
do something
}
```

You may need a `using System.Linq;`

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
public static bool FindValueFromArray(object[] Values,object valueToSearch){
    bool retVal = false;
    Array myArray = (Array)Values;
    int found = Array.BinarySearch(myArray, valueToSearch);
    if (found != -1){
        retVal = true;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've +1. But I'd add that sorting is required and it is only really worth it if you are doing repeated searches.